# I keep being asked by iTunes for password and credit card verification, and getting warning emails

Tags: itunes, windows, accounts, apple-id

I use iTunes (latest available build) on Windows 7 x64.

Whenever I buy apps for my iPhone, or download free updates to apps I already purchased, iTunes asks me to enter my Apple ID password, and my credit card confirmation number; everytime this happens, I also get an email from Apple saying "you purchased something from a device that has never been associated with your account, watch out because someone could be messing around with it".

I always used iTunes only on this computer, and I've tried logging out/in, and also unauthorizing the system and then authorizing it back again; but this keeps happening.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have any security sotware that might be preventing iTunes from writing some sort of cookie or certificate file that is later checked to see if this machine has been "cleared" - I don't think there is an article listing exactly where this file is stored, but you might want to try same in a new user on the OS to rule out iTunes library or folder permission issues.

Comment: I'm using a full Administrator account, UAC is disabled and I have no external security software around; also, no problems of this sort on any website using cookies for authentication (including this very one).

Comment: Good - do note that iTunes is the browser and won't be using any other file than one it designates for storage of the secure key or whatever it does to validate your account. It could also be a problem on the Apple side and you need to get help from someone that can check your account to make sure it isn't flagged server side for potential compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through various rounds of support calls and emails with Apple, there was no way to solve the problem. However, after some months, it just disappeared. I never actually found out what was causing it, probably some glitch on the Apple side.

Meh.

Answer (score 0):

After resetting my AppleID password because I haven’t used it for a long time, it was not required when running iTunes unless I purchased something from the store.

Resetting your AppleID password may fix your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! You've posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. I removed your question here, but If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.